# Replace list item with image

Tags: css, html, navigationbar, image-replacement

I would like to replace a list item with an image.

The list item I wish to replace is the first list item class="main-logo".

My questions are as follows.

1.Do I do the replacement on the .main-logo or on the .logo? 2.What is the best technique to replace the list item with image? 3. If i wish to adjust the line-height of the list items, do i adjust the li class, the nav class or the a class?

thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/codermax/fe0L3d08/4/

```
<nav class = "side-bar">
        <ul class ="main-bar">
            <li class="logo"><a href="#" class="main-logo">Logo</a></li>
            <li class="user-nav"><a href="#" class="big-box">User</a></li>
            <li class="main-nav"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="main-nav"><a href="#">Visitor List</a></li>
            <li class="main-nav"><a href="#">Visualization</a></li>
            <li class="main-nav"><a href="#">History</a></li>
            <li class="divider-nav"><a href="#">Manage</a></li>
            <li class="manage-nav"><a href="#">Agents</a></li>
            <li class="manage-nav"><a href="#">Departments</a></li>
            <li class="manage-nav"><a href="#">Shortcuts</a></li>
            <li class="manage-nav"><a href="#">Banned Visitors</a></li>
            <li class="manage-nav"><a href="#">Triggers</a></li>
            <li class="divider-nav"><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
            <li class="settings-nav"><a href="#">Widgets</a></li>
            <li class="settings-nav"><a href="#">Personal</a></li>
            <li class="settings-nav"><a href="#">Accounts</a></li>
        </ul>
   </nav>
```

the css code.

```
.main-bar li a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: auto 0;
    margin: auto 0;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
 }

article {
    width: 60%;
    height: 30%;
    float: right;
    position: relative; 
}

.logo {
    height: 4em;
}

a.main-logo {
    background: url(zopim.jpg) no-repeat;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

a.big-box {
    line-height: 7em;
    height: 7em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Do I do the replacement on the .main-logo or on the .logo?

Do it on the `.logo` because it's the list item.

> What is the best technique to replace the list item with image?

If you want to replace the content of the list item. From the word `logo` to an image, then just replace it with an `<img>` element. Besides it's the navbar you're working on, you most probably have only one navbar per page so it's okay if you don't do it using CSS.

> If i wish to adjust the line-height of the list items, do i adjust the li class, the nav class or the a class?

The `li` class since it's the *(and i quote)* **"list items"** you want to adjust.

Answer (score 0):

***1.Do I do the replacement on the .main-logo or on the .logo?***

I would personally do it on the `.main-logo` as you have `a` tags set to block and can control it a little better. And it's the most specific.

***2.What is the best technique to replace the list item with image?***

How you have it in your CSS already. Then set the `line-height` to something really high (e.g. `999em`) and set `overflow:hidden`.

***3. If i wish to adjust the line-height of the list items, do i adjust the li class, the nav class or the a class?***

Doesn't matter a ton, but I would personally do the `a` as it's the most specific.

Answer (score 0):

**1.Do I do the replacement on the .main-logo or on the .logo?**

The .logo, of course, You want to style the li, so that's what you need to target

**2.What is the best technique to replace the list item with image?**
It differs from one developer to another, but my personal favorite, and I think the most used one, is the background technique. Like this:

```
li{list-style-type:none; padding-left:30px; background: transparent url(bullet.png) no-repeat 50% 0; background-size:100% auto /* this could vary depending on your needs */}
```

**3. If i wish to adjust the line-height of the list items, do i adjust the li class, the nav class or the a class?**

again, the `li element`. If you want to target an element, that's what you need to style. Think about this: what if you don't have an `a element` inside the li? what if the nav has another style (it probably will)? So, again, just style the element you need to style. And this is true in 99% of situations with CSS